# Where to use aggregate function in select or having

Tags: sql

I'm learning sql and am confused with understanding where to put an aggregate function. I'm using a free test site to experiment with queries. Example

I get the same result when I do the following:
Aggregate function only in "`select`"

```
Select
  day(admission_date) as "Admissions Date",
  count(patient_id)
from 
  admissions
group by 
  day(admission_date)
order by count(*) desc
```

Result

```
Admissions Date   count(patient_id)
11                184
4                 184
9                 183
2                 180
```

Aggregate function also included in "`having`"

```
Select
  day(admission_date) as "Admissions Date",
  count(patient_id)
from 
  admissions
group by 
  day(admission_date)
having
  count(patient_id)
order by count(*) desc
```

Result

```
Admissions Date   count(patient_id)
11                184
4                 184
9                 183
2                 180
```

Both end up with the same result. I'm confused and unsure the rules when to use an aggregate function between "`select`" and "`having`" and also when does "`select`" actually get applied? To me , "`select`" means show me these columns in this format e.g. "`count`"

Comment: Your use of *having* here is irrelevant - you *should* be using it to filter on the aggregation, for example `having count(patient_id) < 180` - as is it's probably being evaluated as a boolean expression `true` for every row.

Comment: I'd expect an error here, your HAVING condition isn't valid. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I can highly recommend a tutorial - you'll get a far more in depth understanding than asking a question here.

Comment: Thank you. I've been reading articles but they haven't been able to drive down to an answer I can fully appreciate. I don't know what the site uses, I imagine it's using mysql

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `having` to filter results. E.g. in your case `having count(patient_id)` does not filter out any results. You should have something like `having count(patient_id) > 1`. It looks in your dbms `having count(patient_id)` returns `true` all the time.

Comment: very helpful .So Having is always about filtering - nice condensed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the confusion, let me clarify the usage of aggregate functions and the difference between using them in the `SELECT` clause and the `HAVING` clause.

Aggregate Functions in `SELECT` clause:
When you use an aggregate function in the `SELECT` clause, it transforms the result set by performing a calculation on a set of values from the rows that are part of the group defined by the `GROUP BY` clause. In your first query, you're calculating the count of patient IDs for each day of admission and displaying it in the result set. The `SELECT` clause is applied to the individual rows before they are grouped.

Aggregate Functions in `HAVING` clause:
The `HAVING` clause is used to filter the result set after the `GROUP BY` clause has been applied. It filters groups based on aggregate calculations. In your second query, when you put `count(patient_id)` in the `HAVING` clause, you are filtering the groups such that only groups with a non-zero count of patient IDs will be included in the final result.

In the second query:

```
Select
  day(admission_date) as "Admissions Date",
  count(patient_id)
from 
  admissions
group by 
  day(admission_date)
having
  count(patient_id)
order by count(*) desc
```

Since the `count(patient_id)` is always greater than zero (since you're counting non-null values), it has the same effect as not having the `HAVING` clause at all. Therefore, both queries will yield the same result

To summarize

Use aggregate functions in the `SELECT` clause to perform calculations on groups of rows before they are grouped.
Use the `HAVING` clause to filter groups based on aggregate calculations after the grouping has been done.
If you want to apply a condition on the aggregate calculation in the `HAVING` clause, you might use comparison operators like `HAVING COUNT(patient_id) > 100`, which would only show groups with a count greater than 100.

Remember that the `SELECT` clause is used to determine the columns and expressions that will appear in the final result set, while the `HAVING` clause filters the grouped result set based on aggregate calculations.